# Button won't stay in respect to background image

Tags: html, css, button, background

I tried researching this question on this site, but everything wasn't related to my particular site. Pretty much I have a background image on my home page, and the background is "fixed" and "covered". I am not sure if that's the reason why it is not working. I want the "View Works" button in the center of the computer. Please help!

HTML:

```
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Kasia's Website </title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="works.html">
      <input class="butt" type="button" value="VIEW WORKS" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="page">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div>
        <a href="index.html"><img id="logo"    
    src="http://i66.tinypic.com/xnf4us.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="sb">
          <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a> </li>
          <li><a href="about.html"> About</a> </li>
          <li><a href="works.html"> Works</a> </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div id="sidebar-btn">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

       </div>


      <script    
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">  
    </script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
              $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
          });

      });
    </script>

    </div>


    </body>

    </html>
```

CSS

```
  @charset "UTF-8";
body {
  background-image: url(http://i66.tinypic.com/ww1d7n.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}

#sidebar {
  background: #05E2D4;
  background-color: rgba(5, 226, 212, 0.7);
  width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  top: 0px;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

#sidebar.visible {
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

ul.sb {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 200px;
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 105;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  line-height: 30%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#sidebar-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px;
  top: 0px;
  right: -60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sidebar-btn span {
  height: 2px;
  background: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:visited {
  color: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ffcd03;
}

a:active {
  color: #ffcd03;
}

#logo {
  margin: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
}

#page {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 600px;
}

#Kasiaport {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px 200px 50px 200px;
}

aside {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 40px 40px 20px 40px;
  margin: auto;
}

p.work {
  color: white;
  font-size: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
  display: block;
}

.butt {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #FFFFFF 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-top: 32%;
  position: absolute;
}

.butt:hover {
  border-color: #ffcd03;
  background-color: none;
  color: #ffcd03;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/kasiariele/pen/MaLdWv/

In order to see the error visually, you may need to go in full screen mode (http://codepen.io/kasiariele/full/MaLdWv/) or make the screen smaller so you can see it scroll.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `margin` to "center" your elements as you did.

You can add this code and the `button` will be centered both horizontally and vertically without having to adjust your old code:

```
.butt {
  margin: 0; /* reset your old margin */
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Check [browser support for transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) and any extra prefixes needed (`-ms` for ie9).

Comment: Thanks.
How do I get the button to stay put even when I adjust the size of the window? Right now, it moves, and I want it to stay put.

http://www.squarespace.com/
For example squarespace has a centered button on a background image that even when I changed the size (or dragged the sides of the window) it stays in place.

Comment: @KasiaAriele did you put the styling rule I included above in your code? That *should* keep the button centered throughout all browser resizing

Comment: yes, it is centered. I think I wasn't clear enough. I want it centered in relation to my background image. So like the center of the computer screen. Would my only solution be a media query, or changing the position from fixed to scroll instead?

Comment: @KasiaAriele he above css rules centers the button relative to the browser window; so no matter how you `resize` your browser it will always be vertically and horizontally centered. If by `computer screen` you mean the screen **in** your `background-image`, then you will have to make sure you background image is centered as well (`background-position: center;`); if the button doesn't like up to that, then adjust your `bg-image` so the screen in always centered - you could use `@media` rule to line the button with `screen`, but you'll never have perfect 100% of the time

Comment: Oh okay, got it. If I changed the `background-image` to `scroll` would that make it easier to make my button adapt to the image? Or should I create a Div within the html to make the  background `relative` and the button `absolute` .

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229483/css-position-button-inside-image is sort of what I am looking for, but it doesn't answer my question for a background image. Not a regular image.

Comment: I don't think you need to create another `div` - i was fiddling around and think I cam up with a good way to do what you're after - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/punx2b61/1/)** -  let me know if this is what you want, I tested resizing the `output` window and the `button` stays relatively close to origin position

Comment: Sort of. I want the button to stay RIGHT in the middle of the computer screen. When I resize & scroll on the browser. And that's why I assumed the `background-image` might need to be on scroll.

Comment: @KasiaAriele change the `button` to `position: fixed` - **[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/punx2b61/2/)** that's likely the best you're going to get with a `background-image` - if it was *me* I would approach this differently, but I don't want to digress from the original question

Comment: @KasiaAriele if this answer or any other has helped you and provided a useful solution to your question, [please consider accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this